# How can I completely remove OneSignal library?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, onesignal

I am trying to completely remove OneSignal library , 
I have deleted its library from dependencies

This is gradle app code

```
plugins {
id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   }
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
 }

 repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:2.2.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.whalemare:sheetmenu:1.3.3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**The problem** is that I can't remove this line

```
plugins {
id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.8.1'
}
```

when I delete it and put `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in the first line

I get this error

[image]

How can I fix this error ? Or What is the right way to remove OneSignal ?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong version of the `appcompat-v7` library i.e. `26.1.0` instead of `27.1.0`. Also, you've to use the `support-compat` library:

```
def final support_libraries_version = '27.1.0'
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_libraries_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${support_libraries_version}"
```

which means you'll also have to change your compile sdk version to `27`:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
```

Comment: Thanks for help .. I have edited `compileSdkVersion` to version `27` and updated all support libraries to version `27` , but I got the same error again !

Comment: @PearlAdams Your support library version should be at least `27.0.2`. Which one did you use?

Comment: I use this version `27.1.0`

Comment: @PearlAdams see my edited answer : you've to add the `support-compat` library as well

Comment: I already use it 
`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'`  
   `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'`
    `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'`